Is it more likely that ftm are gay/bisexual than mtf?
What I read online is mostly about gay/bisexual ftm but rarely about gay/bisexual mtf.
According to some studies, women are more likely to be bisexual than men. So is this the case as well for ftm? Any related studies?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_sexual_orientation#:~:text=Bisexuals%20accounted%20for%201.3%25%20of,same%2Dsex%20attraction%20and%20experience.

Welcome. Can you expand your question with some background, and at the very least spell out the abbreviations?
